# Laravel test not passing

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-7, laravel-testing

So I'm learning doing tests for my application and one of the tests it doesn't want to pass, and here it is the logic: Basically, when a user request the home page, I expect that the database list count would be 0, and this passed, then I expect also that the session has an error key of `NoBook` and here it fails. this is the code that i have tried:

```
class BookDisplayManagmentTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function Show_error_message_when_there_is_no_book_to_display_in_index_page()
    {
        //Request the home page
        $response = $this->get(route('home'));

        // I expect the count on the database book equal 0
        $this->assertCount(0, book::all());

        //Then I also expect that the session will flash an error with key NoBook
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors('NoBook');
    }

}
```

But the problem I'm getting this error:

```
Session is missing expected key [errors]. Failed asserting that false is true.
```

And the code that add the session error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Books;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
      /** @show index function */
        public function index()
        {
            $book = Books::paginate(7);
            if(!$book->count())
            {
                session()->now('NoBook','There is no books at the moment');
            }
            return view('index', compact('book'));
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that would add the error to the session?

Comment: if(!$Book->count())
            {
                session()->now('NoBook','There is no books at the moment');
            }

Comment: Please add the code to your initial question 

Comment: try adding `$this->assertSessionHasErrors();` before  `$response->assertSessionHasErrors('NoBook');`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert i did add the code

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yes i added $this->assertSessionHasErrors() getting the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `session()` which is adding a key to the session which is **not an error key**.

Therefore, since you are not passing an error from your Controller - then your test is "successfully" failing.

If you want to pass on an error to the session, you have to use MessageBag such as using the following code:

```
      /** @show index function */
        public function index()
        {
            $book = Books::paginate(7);
            $errors = [];

            if(!$book->count())
            {
                $errors['NoBook'] = 'There is no books at the moment';
            }
            return view('index', compact('book'))->withErrors($errors);
        }
```

Comment: I'm passing the session error session()->now('NoBook','There is no books at the moment'); and i tried your code didn't work also

Comment: Please check the updated explanation and fixed code

Comment: Thank you very much i did understand now what is happening, thank you again :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Writing test is a good way to keep good coding standards, keep coding and don't forget to pass by StackOverflow to share your knowledge 